# What do I do after getting the spell to control people?

Tags: overlord-2

I'm just learning Overlord 2, and I've reached the point where I get the spell to control/kill townspeople.  I've controlled 3 of them like it instructed me too.  But I can't figure out what to do next.  I seem to be blocked on both sides by firecracker "walls", and it told me I can't get through them until I find my red minions, but I don't seem to be able to summon red minions yet.  What am I supposed to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, you had to control 3 of them AND kill 3 of them with the spell in order to have it let you progress.